excel keeps changing operators in multilingual sheet (Farsi for texts and English for numbers)
Excel keeps changing operators in multilingual sheet (Farsi for texts and English for numbers). For example when I try to type in "52.1429" it changes "." to a "/" and the number becomes a division "52/1429" so number "0.04" fills the cell.
Or... Lets assume I want to fill H3 cell with product of H1 and H2 multiplication. when I write "=H1*H2" in H3 Formula Bar, excel rejects the operation and fills the cell with "#VALUE!" and the error message is this: "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type."
For the problem with decimal numbers I tried copy-pasting the number from places that I think they are in English for sure (like browser address bar or a plain text editor); Or using alphanumeric section of keyboard instead of using the numpad. In both situations I believe the final number is treated as text/string data.
Or even assuming the "/" character that excel uses looks like a Slash but actually is not a slash I tried to editing the decimal number in H3 cell. I changed the whole number part to 52 and without touching the character in decimal point position I changed the fractional part to 1429. Again after pressing the Enter key the result is 0.04 (0/0363890832750175 unformatted, the same number I just edited)!
For my problem with formula part I tried to use "=PRODUCT(H1,H2)" in H3 cell. This time an error message pops-up with this sentence in the first row: "There's a problem with this formula.
Also while typing the template that pops up in tool-tip is: "PRODUCT(number1;[number2];...)". Filling the formula with this format "=PRODUCT(H1;H2)" results in 0 and the Latin semicolon in formula turns into a Persian semicolon "؛".
Any thoughts?

I'm using "Persian (Standard) keyboard" alongside "US keyboard" and I use "Alt+Shift" to switch between them. The regional format is set to "Persian (Iran)". Also I'm using "Microsoft Office LTSC Professional Plus 2021" with Persian Language Pack installed, on a Windows 10 machine.
All the cells on H column are formatted as number.

I was adding this comment to mention a workaround I used for entering 2.5 last night. I typed in 5/2. But now while writing this comment I tried to verify it on 52.1429 by typing 521429/10000, now it works as I expected it to in the first place, the result is 521429/1.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1ZF960P0ck

The behavior is as expected - decimal symbol in Persian (Iran) regional setting defaults to /, you can view it via Control Panel:
Regional Setting Control Panel

Input behavior with decimal separator as / in cells with

'General' format

works as expected when entering numerical values


'Number' format: entering / causes division instead of being treated as decimal separator, for example

entering 4.2 via number pad
will change to 4/2 and then to 2/00



Using Custom Separators instead of system setting seem to eliminate these problems. It is safe to change since the numbers are stored correctly regardless of the separators chosen.
Changing the option:

Excel > File > Options > Advanced > Turn Off "Use System Separators"
for Decimal / thousands set a desired pair, for example

. and , or
, and . (common in EU and other regions)




I appreciate your time and attention. I'm adding the details to original post.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@nkalvi not yet. I'm stumped.

@nkalvi  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1ZF960P0ck

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@nkalvi Thank you for dedicating your time and effort to solving my problem. But I'm a bit hesitant to change my language default settings, I'm afraid that it may cause problems for my accounting program that I have on my system.

@nkalvi If I leave the cells formatting as general pressing "4"+"."+"2" on numpad results in "4/2". In the result cell both "*" and "product" formulas are smart enough to interpret "4/2" as a decimal number. (This even works with reverting the Office Language Options).
But if I format the cell as any kind of number, "4"+"."+"2" on numpad results in "2/00"

@Farshid, I was also stumped but a simple option change seems to help. Please try the steps in the updated answer and let me know.

@nkalvi Well... That's a bingo! I was not ready to modify the decimal point character system wide. But if this only affects Excel sheets I'll accept it. Actually I prefer it this way.

Happy to hear it! Didn't know inputting numbers could be difficult in Excel :) BTW, you may want to delete the other comments.
